# git warning "unable to access permission denied" on a .gitignore directory

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a sub-directory called ".gitignore" in one of my directories called "Database", which I want git to ignore, so I listed it in my .gitingore file.

.gitignore:

```
    [Bb]in/
    [Dd]ebug/
    [Rr]elease/
    .gitignore/
```

When I perform a command like git status Database, i get the following warning:

```
warning: unable to access 'Database/.gitignore': Permission denied
```

Can anyone please help me understand what I can do to get rid of this warning?

PS: I verified folder permissions on both "Database" and ".gitingore" were the same.

PS: I am running git on Windows 8. I don't think this matters.

Comment: Sorry for the poor naming choice. I have .gitingore file in the root of my branch and I created a sub-directory in one of my directories with the name .gitignore also. I did it to avoid having to use one new name, but as @MichaelJones suggested, use a different name for the directory!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're experiencing but I would imagine that having a **folder** called `.gitignore` is a bad idea. Git might be trying to open it and read it like a file as it needs to know the contents of `.gitignore` files.

Try calling it something else and then adding its name to a `.gitignore` file next to it in the directory.

Comment: I thought naming a folder ".gitignore" may not cause a collision however as you suspected, it did! I am calling it ".ignorefiles" now.

Comment: When you create a repo in git hub and clone it, ignore files are placed in a folder named .gitignore. And I get the same error, `warning: unable to access '.gitignore': Permission denied` What can I do? I can't seem to be able to rename the folder either

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not sure what you are referring to as I haven't experienced it. Do you have a link? Otherwise maybe consider posting a separate question regarding that?

Answer (score 0):

Copy your .gitignore file and paste it on your desktop. Then open it and make changes. Delete previous file in your folder and paste updated one.

Hidden files cannot be replaced or edited.