# Git warning: unable to access '.gitignore': Permission denied - .gitignore directory

Tags: git, github, gitignore

I created a repo on github, created a .gitignore file and then cloned it to my PC. After which I added my files, committed and pushed them.

Gitignore doesn't work as intended and I get this warning:

[image]

Inside local repo folder structure:

[image]

Why isn't .gitignore accessible? Is it because it's in a separate folder?
What should I do to solve this?

I can't seem to be able to rename it as suggested by this answer:[similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25138119/3724463)

Comment: `.gitignore` must be a file - not a folder.

Comment: @JacobWood inside the folder is the file I created. I have no idea why github created it like that.

Comment: Move the file out of the folder and delete the folder.

Comment: @JacobWood That seems to solve the issue. Thanks! however I'd still like to know why that happened when cloning the project from GitHub

Comment: It doesn't appear as a directory on github? If it's a public repo, mind linking so I can try and reproduce?

Comment: It did appear as a directory named .gitignore. Inside which was the .gitignore file.

Comment: Then it's not an issue that occurs in cloning it, rather, an issue created by whoever structured the repo that way.

Comment: @JacobWood Linked to the fixed commit https://github.com/sndnshr/algorithms-Princeton/commit/c59e9cfd7c8718e43dba3f960db5c0cd8128aeef

Comment: Is there anything missing to my answer? Moving the .gitignore from its .gitignore folder should solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

> inside the folder is the file I created. I have no idea why github created it like that

First, as mention, you do not create files inside a `.gitignore` folder: you [declare file patterns](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_description) in a `.gitignore` text file.

Second, check if the `.gitignore` is displayed as a folder in your GitHub repo.
If not, try and clone that repo again (in another local path) from command-line (and not GitHub Desktop)

```
git clone https://github.com/<user>/<myrepo.git>
```

Check then if the .gitignore is correctly created (as a file)

The OP confirms:

> Yes, in the GitHub repo there's a `.gitignore` folder, inside it `.gitignore` file is placed

So:

```
.gitignore/.gitignore
```

Comment: Yes, in the GitHub repo there's a .gitignore folder, inside it .gitignore file is placed. I did use git bash to clone previously.

Comment: @Sndn do you know what created that .gitignore/.gitignore folder/file?