# .gitignore file Permission denied

Tags: git, gitignore

I do not know what I did but I keep getting this error. I had two remotes origin and test of a local copy of a repository.  I deleted the test remote and I wanted to use back again the origin. And now I get an error like

**unable to access .gitignore. Permission denied**

And when I want to push some commits I am getting

> error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/me/Test'
>   hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
>   hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
>   hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
>   hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

[image]

Comment: Do what the error tells you to do. 'git pull origin master', then try to commit and push back.

Comment: I did that but it still gives the error with .gitignore permission denied

Comment: Try to delete the .gitignore file and then recreate it. Make sure that .gitignore is really a file and not a folder
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25137925/git-warning-unable-to-access-permission-denied-on-a-gitignore-directory

Comment: Is a file. It does not let me delete it because it says that I have to have permissions of an admin, but I am admin. It worked 1 hour ago, I do not know why now does not word

Answer (score 0):

- `.gitignore` must be a file - not a folder.
- Use

  - `git pull upstream`
  - Push the changes to forked repo with  `-f` push.

I hope this helps.

Comment: with git push -f its says everything up to date. But the error with .gitignore still is. Is a file in base directory

Comment: Can you please add a screenshot of the repo directory?

Comment: Yes, I added in the post